# react native - paddingTop with percentage value doesn't work

Tags: react-native

refer to [react native padding top doc](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#paddingtop)

> paddingTop works like padding-top in CSS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top for more details.

and on [css link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding-top) there's some percentage in padding-top, but it doesn't work in react native,

how can I add percentage in paddingTop react native?

Answer (score 5):

React Native supports a percentage value since v0.42.3 ([changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases?after=v0.43.0)). You can refer to this [commit](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/3f49e743bea730907066677c7cbfbb1260677d11).

Answer (score 2):

Can't specify percentage in react native css.

To specify percentage by getting the screen size and convert it into percentage.

Sample example:

```
const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');

paddingTop: height * 0.1 // 10 percentage of the screen height
```

Answer (score 0):

in React Native, for paddingTop: "5%"
only the % is working, number, number in string are not working with the latest as on 17 April 2019.

Answer (score 0):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    flex:1,
    paddingLeft: 24,
    paddingRight: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    paddingBottom:"5%"
  },
  inner: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    marginTop:"10%"
  },
});
```